# De-duplicating based off two fields in Tableau Prep

Tags: duplicates, tableau-api, data-cleaning

If I have the following data with two fields, Person ID and Action Date:
[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYLCl.png)

I want to remove duplicate ID rows but keep the row with the latest date.

I have tried various calculated filters based around `COUNTD` but honestly getting very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Create a calculated field and write below table calculation:

```
IF WINDOW_MAX(MAX([Action Date])) = MAX([Action Date])
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END
```

Compute the table calculation as `Specify Dimensions` and reset for every `ID`

Now use this in filter and check `True`

Answer (score 1):

Create calculated field **[Filter]**:

```
{FIXED [Person ID]: MAX([Action Date])} = [Action Date]
```

then place it on a filter shelf, selecting only True values. Finally right click this pill on filter shelf and select **Add to context**

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau Prep, use the `Aggregate` step. Put **Person ID** in `Grouped Fields` and **Action Date** in `Aggregated Fields`. Choose `MAX` for the operation in `Aggregated Fields`.